# Best Practice for different pages in an DART app

Tags: dart, dart-html

What´s the best practice for different pages in an app, which are for example called from a menue.

Would you create for a new page this page in DOM and destroy the old one or is it better to hide the oldones (could be more of course)?

Or is there another better way?

Thanks Mica

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the DOM size when all views are inserted into the DOM but hidden.
If it's to big it may make more sense to insert/remove otherwise just show/hide.
It also depends on the probability that the other views will be displayed.

Comment: tnx, can you give me an idea, what could be a critical size.

Comment: I think this is a plain HTML/Browser question that has nothing specific to Dart. I have no concrete values from experience or benchmarks available. I just saw that Browsers are getting slow and need to much memory when pages are too big. But I can't say when big is too big.